# Can not enable Gzip (not on a shared host)

Tags: php, .htaccess, compression, gzip

so I pasted following into my .htaccess (www.storyfollower.com):

```
#Gzip
# compress the files
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript
# removes some bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
#End Gzip
```

But when using yslow I get following:
Compressing http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js could save 64.9KiB (64% reduction).
Compressing http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js could save 50.3KiB (65% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/jquery.js could save 50.3KiB (65% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/js/jquery-1.4.min.js could save 45.0KiB (66% reduction).
Compressing http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/widget76.css could save 29.4KiB (78% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/js/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.js could save 12.6KiB (73% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js could save 9.2KiB (66% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/js/facebox.js could save 6.3KiB (69% reduction).
Compressing http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js could save 5.9KiB (66% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/jquery.freeow.js could save 3.9KiB (71% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/js/basic.js could save 3.8KiB (75% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/css/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.css could save 3.5KiB (78% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/style/freeow/freeow.css could save 3.2KiB (72% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/js/liteaccordion.jquery.js could save 3.1KiB (64% reduction).
Compressing http://www.youtube.com/embed/u7pTrqFU5MY?hd=1 could save 2.9KiB (62% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/css/mobile.css could save 2.9KiB (70% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/css/styles.css could save 2.8KiB (71% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/css/liteaccordion.css could save 2.4KiB (69% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/css/common.css could save 1.8KiB (64% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/js/jquery.elastic.js could save 973B (57% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/css/facebox.css could save 900B (65% reduction).
Compressing http://storyfollower.com/css/jquery.autocomplete.css could save 359B (45% reduction).

Compress all content is enabled in Cpanel!
Also this is a dedicated Server!

Thanks

Comment: Who is managing the server? Ask them to activate it in the central configuration.

Comment: it is activated (other sited use it) like http://codepigeon.com (still under dev.) is also hosted there

Comment: Clear your browsers cache. gzip is enabled on storyfollower.com. The problem is that yslow checkes the cached files, and doesn't see the updated response-headers, that have gzip enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it some time... clearing browser cache yslow checkes the cached files